# Ajax response contains more than expected

Tags: ajax, request, response

**Filestructure**

js/scripts.js

library/libary.php

modules/page.php

modulus/404.php

index.php

**Explanation of the files**

index.php looks what the path part of the url is, and require that file. So www.test.com/page will require modules/page.php. Some code:

```
$file = (DIR . 'modules/'.$action.'.php');
if(!file_exists($file))
{
    $file = DIR . 'modules/404.php';
}

//Get file
require($file);
```

The body of page.php looks like this:

```
<input type='submit' value='getTime' onClick='getTime()' />
```

The JS function looks like this:

```
function updateStatus()
   {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","library/library.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("status=page");
    }
```

And the library file contains something like this:

```
return time();
```

**Problem**

The problem is that the reponseText doesn't contain the time only, it also contains the 404.php page. This is because of my index.php. He looks for a modules/library.php, and it doensn't exists (not in de the modules dir).

So my question is, what is the way of an ajax request and response? And how do I solve this problem without putting the library.php in the modules dir?

My real problem is a bit more complex, but its in it roots the same problem as I described here. So getting the time is not my issue, its only a thing to illustrate my problem.